# Animated textures with react-three-fibre

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using the package [three-plain-animator](https://codesandbox.io/s/not-working-animated-texture-o1drw) for animated textures to be shown in my mesh. I am using react-three-fibre instead of plain three.js and for some reason, it loads the texture but doesn't animate it. Here is my [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-haze-o1drw) to show what I mean. I even tried not using `useLoader` and copied the example supplied in the docs exactly:

```
const texturePath = 'https://i.imgur.com/Oj6RJV9.png';
const animator = new PlainAnimator(new THREE.TextureLoader().load(texturePath), 4, 4, 10, 10);
const texture = animator.init();
```

Does this package only work with plain three.js? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

So @hpalu kindly pointed out that my previous answer wasn't the best as it leads to multiple loops being rendered at the same time which was visualized [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wrong-code-with-hover-effect-tr3o4) when I tried to create hover events.

Here is @hpalu 's working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-colden-8juy5?file=/src/Sprite.js) with the updated code that utilizes useFrame which allows components to participate in the render function which is called 60 times/second.

As you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/working-animated-texture-with-hover-3q9uw), the mouse event is working well with this code with no complications

***Original answer:***

Okay so from looking at the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-animations) provided in the documentation. It looks like I was missing the `animator.animate()` within the animate function. So I had to include this function within my sprite function export:

```
  const animate = () => {
    animator.animate();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };
```

And then in the return section I called the animate function:

```
  return (
    <>
      <mesh/>
      </mesh>
      {animate()}
    </>
  )
```

Here is my updated sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/animated-texture-fep1e)

Comment: this could be "dangerous", as in, you're putting side effects into the render function. another render and the animation loop will run twice for instance. this is where useFrame comes in, it allows components to participate in the render function which is called 60 times/second: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-colden-8juy5

ps. there's also https://spectrum.chat/react-three-fiber - usually you get help super quick

Comment: @hpalu Yes you are absolutely right, as I realised quickly when adding events using useEffect, it would render the loop multiple times and then react like crazy. Thank you so much for your help, I will change my answer. However, I do have a question, I realised you put the  `useFrame(() => animator.animate())`  but I can't seem to find an animate function that it's calling so I don't understand how it's working. I thought maybe it is part of react-three-fiber but I looked through the documentation and I can't seem to find it. Sorry if this seems like an obvious question.

Comment: r3f is also running in a loop, useFrame subscribes components to it. so basically it executes the function inside in r3f's internal raf loop. and all the other subscribers. this makes it easy to use loop-reliant addons (controls, animation, etc) and is also very efficient, because having more than one requestanimationframe-loop has negative impact on performance. you can also use useFrame for frame based animations, for instance: https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-contact-shadow-3iv32