# Animated GIF spotlight map

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to use a water caustic gif as a gobo for a threejs pointlight.  Currently the gif is only showing the first frame.  I tried to modify [Sophia98's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030786/animated-textures-with-react-three-fibre) for animating textures, but haven't been able to make it work:

```
function Sprite({ textureSrc, IconPosition, IconSize }) {
  const spriteTexture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, textureSrc)
  const [animator] = useState(() => new PlainAnimator(spriteTexture, 4, 4, 10, 10))
  useFrame(() => animator.animate())
  return (
      <spotLight position={[0, 10, 0]} intensity={1} color="#fff" map={spriteTexture} />
  )
}

<Suspense fallback={null}>
  <Sprite IconPosition={[2, 1, 0]} IconSize={[3, 3, 0]} textureSrc="./3s0F.gif" />
</Suspense>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set [`Texture.needsUpdate = true`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.needsUpdate) on each frame? It'swhat VideoTexture does under the hood to refresh the image.

Comment: Hmm, would I add it here?

function Sprite({ textureSrc, IconPosition, IconSize }) {
  const spriteTexture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, textureSrc)
  const [animator] = useState(() => new PlainAnimator(spriteTexture, 4, 4, 10, 10))
  useFrame(() => animator.animate())
  spriteTexture.needsUpdate = true;
  return (
      <spotLight position={[0, 10, 0]} intensity={1} color="#fff" map={spriteTexture}  />
  )
}

It's still static.

Comment: I downloaded a .mp4 to try in case videoTexture was easier.  const videoTexture = useVideoTexture("./water.mp4") <pointLight position={[0, 500, 0]} intensity={1} color="#fff" map={videoTexture} />.  No dice, its not even showing the first frame.

Comment: AH!  I got it working with the videoTexture, if you look at my comment above I accidentally added it to the pointLight instead of the spotLight.

Comment: @Ashbury Glad to hear it worked! If my solution helped you, please consider voting on it.